# How to apply regex to matchcollection?

Tags: c#, regex

I currently have a MatchCollection that looks like the following:

```
MatchCollection MatchA = Regex.Matches(Source, Pattern);
```

I'm using `foreach (Match OutputA in MatchA)` to output each result on an individual line in a `richtextbox`. Afterwards, I run a second regex, like the following:

```
MatchCollection MatchB = Regex.Matches(richtextbox1.text, Pattern);
```

This feels convoluted. How can I apply the second regex (MatchB) directly to the results of the first regex (MatchA)?

In other words, I want to do the following, but, of course, it doesn't actually work:

```
MatchCollection MatchB = Regex.Matches(MatchA, Pattern);
```

Comment: So you want to apply the second regex on each match of the first? Why not just use a loop?

Comment: What is the final result? Are you adding text to rich text box temporarily to replace with new matches? Then you should think of using the right regex at Step 1. Or use Step 2 to filter out unwanted matches before adding to the rich textbox.

Comment: `Foreach(match m in something)` is the behavior you are looking for. I think that if you provide you regex we should be able to see if you are not just using the wrong one. It sums up to one thing: [MCVE]

Comment: The current process: Get string -> MatchA on string -> foreach match to output results into richtextbox -> MatchB on richtextbox.text -> Using MatchB[INDEX] to return the information I want /// Although the code works completely fine right now, I want to get rid of the richtextbox step, if that's possible.

Comment: [edit] information directly in your question. So you can had format and make it readable ^^

Comment: To me, this just seems like you need more nested repeating groups inside your original regex...